# How can I include additional models in a subcontroller?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, mvc

So I have a subcontroller extending `JControllerForm` that handles the `edit` view of an item in my component.

As part of this I'd like to render some associated items, which come from a different DB table and are associated in a 1-M relationship with that table.

How can I add that model in `JControllerForm` so that it's ready for use in `view.html.php`?

The only real solution I've seen is to have a `switch` statement in the master controller `display()` method to identify the view and add models at that point, but it strikes me with all these subcontrollers that some method must be overrideable?

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet directly on view.html.php:

```
$model = $this->getModel('NameOfModel','NameOfComponent', array('ignore_request' => false));
$model->myMethod(yourparam1, yourparam2 etc);
```